# CKFinder Intercepting Before/After Upload Process

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder 2.6 for ASP.NET. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I need to do processing before/after a file is uploaded using the CKFinder. Is there a way to subscribe to `beforeUpload` or `afterUpload` events in CKFinder? I've looked in their documentation, but can't find anything suitable.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you need solution for the server part of CKFinder.

There is no specific `beforeUpload` event. To handle things that happened before upload subscribe to `CKFinderEvent.BeforeExecuteCommand` and check `CKFinderEventArgs` field `data[0]` for `"FileUpload"` or `"QuickUpload"`.

To subscribe to `afterUpload` event subscribe to `CKFinderEvent.AfterFileUpload`.

There are two example plugins that subscribe to `CKFinderEvent.BeforeExecuteCommand` and `CKFinderEvent.AfterFileUpload` events. These are `ImageResize` and `Watermark` respectively.

Comment: Can the AfterFileUpload event be subscribed in the config.ascx file, or does it require modification of the source code (and re-compile)?  Thanks

Comment: @palmej2: `config.ascx` is just for configuration and it doesn't have access to `CKFinderEvent` object. The best way to add event handlers is to implement you own plugin. [Here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Plugins/Writing_ASP.NET) is a documentation on how to do this. In the source code there are also 3 sample plugins: `FileEditor`, `ImageResize` and `Watermark`